# How to update the nested tables in sql using gorm?

Tags: sql, go, foreign-keys, one-to-one, go-gorm

Here the code is written in Go. I am using two tables where one table has a foreign key that refers to the other table's primary key. Let's say I have a database as following struct defined:

```
   type User struct{
       ID uint `gorm:"primary_key;column:id"`
       Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
       Place place
       PlaceID
   }

   type Place struct{
       ID uint `gorm:"primary_key;column:id"`
       Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
       Pincode uint `gorm:"column:pincode"`
   }
```

And the sql schema is:

```
create table place(
    id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    pincode uint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

create table user(
    id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    place_id uint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES place(id)
)
```

Now while inserting in user by gorm as:

```
  place := Place{Name:"new delhi",Pincode:1234}
  user := User{Name: "sam", Age: 15, Place: place}
  err = db.Debug().Create(&user).Error

  //It  inserts to both user and place table in mysql
  //now while updating to name in user table as Samuel and place as 
  //following

  place := Place{Name:"mumbai",Pincode:1234}
  err = db.Debug().Model(&User{}).Where("id =?", 
   1,).Update(&user{Name:"Samuel",Place:place}).Error
```

It updates the row in user table but creates a new row in place table.But it should update the matching row in place table  and not create a new one

Is there any way to do it? Here I am not using auto migrate function to create db tables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question should be sought in a relations or [Association Mode](http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Association-Mode).
The example below shows how to add new associations for ***many to many***, ***has many***, replace current associations for ***has one***, ***belongs to***

```
db.Model(&user).Association("Place").Append(Place{Name:"mumbai",Pincode:1234})
```

Or you can replace current associations with new ones:

`db.Model(&user).Association("Place").Replace(Place{Name:"mumbai",Pincode:1234},Place{Name:"new delhi",Pincode:1234})`

Answer (score 0):

Probably It's creating a new row because you didn't set the ID on `Place{Name:"mumbai",Pincode:1234}`.